# Run a python function depends on the checkbox

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox

I'm working on a python project and I want to call a function if a checkbox was checked. For expample if the yes checkbox was checked the first function will be called. I made this code, but it always calls the second function even if I checked the yes checkbox. I don't know what the issue. Any help is highly appreciated.
this is my html :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="mycheckboxname" value="yes">
<label for="vehicle1"> Without comments</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="mycheckboxname" value="no">
<label for="vehicle2"> With comments</label><br>
```

And this is my view.py

```
def datatable_view(request):   
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = Scraping(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mylist=request.POST.getlist('mycheckboxname')
            if 'yes' in mylist: 
                subject=form.cleaned_data['subject'] 
                scrap(subject)
                client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
                db= client["db2"]
                col = db[subject]
                products = col.find()
                context = {'products' : products}
                return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
            else:
                subject=form.cleaned_data['subject']
                hello(subject)    
                client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
                # use variable names for db and collection reference
                db= client["db2"]
                col = db[subject]
                products = col.find()
                context = {'products' : products}
                #open datatable html and display all the data from database
                return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
    return
```

Comment: What's "mylist"? Does it contain 'yes'?

Comment: mylist is request.POST.getlist('mycheckboxname') which mycheckboxname is the name of the checkbox input which is contain two values yes and no

Comment: Yes, but what does it REALLY contain if you add breakpoint after assigning value to it, run your code in debugger and make request using your form

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: If always second function executes, that means that your if statement condition "'yes' in mylist" is False. That means that "mylist" does not contain 'yes' . By debugging your code you could check what does it contain. Other way is to print 'mylist'